# Why doesn't this SQL UPDATE query work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know SQL well but I must be missing something really dumb here. This update query keeps throwing an error. The query is:

```
UPDATE pages SET 'order' = 1 WHERE id = 19
```

The table definitely has a column for order, and it has a record with the ID of 19. The order column is not unique.

The error I get is the generic one:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"order" = 2 WHERE id = 19' at line 1
```

I've enclosed order in quotation marks because `ORDER` is a reserved SQL word. What am I missing?

Comment: If this is a table that has not yet gone to production, I suggest you change the filed name to something that willnot need to be escaped. This will save a lot of maintenance time as people will forget to do it and then wonder what's wrong. 

In the future, do not use a reserved word for a field name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If using MySQL the query should look like this:

```
UPDATE `pages` SET `order`=1 WHERE `id`=19
```

Comment: Only backticks worked, but you only need them around the reserved word, order. So it's UPDATE pages SET `order`=1 WHERE id = 19 LIMIT 1. I was sure square brackets would have worked, I have to look into why they didn't.

Comment: Note that you don't have to escape every word (as shown in the example). Only `order`.

Comment: Yes, you do not have to escape every word.
But for better understanding (and I think its good practice) to escape the table and row names.
[edit] Here is a list of reserved words foy mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a MySQL error message.  Doesn't MySQL use backticks (`) for escaping?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE pages SET [order] = 1 WHERE id = 19
```

Nevemind MySQL

Comment: Interestingly, that didn't work either. Even though I immediately recognized what you were saying and was sure that was it.

Answer (score 1):

don't use quotes, use [order] (or whatever your sql version uses for escaping). With the regular quotes it is seen as a string literal, which is not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the single quote from the column name specification in the query

```
UPDATE pages SET order = 1 WHERE id = 19 ;
```

Comment: This won't work. ORDER is a reserved word, and so it must be escaped (which is database-specific)

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a reserved word used in  `ORDER BY`.

Use backticks (`) (as Ken said).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is;

```
UPDATE pages SET pages.order = 1 WHERE id = 19 ;
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query should be;

```
UPDATE pages SET order = '1'
WHERE id = 19
```